# Format component to html tag

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

I am importing a class called MapContainer from maps.js and displaying my div files in the App.js. is there a way to change the google api wrapper along side with the api key to work directly in the html tags.

```
import { GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

<div class="content">

GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDkXk3MuVjovvaVAnl2wt2j_2ES-INLJ0s'
})(MapContainer);
          
        </div>
```

I tried several other methods that require to change the code of app.js and maps.js and yet it doesnt work. Hence why I went back hopefully fix the formatting for the div.

ps. the MapContainer is the google map renderer but requires the API key along side it to generate the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `React.createElement`:

```
<div class="content">

{React.createElement(GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDkXk3MuVjovvaVAnl2wt2j_2ES-INLJ0s'
})(MapContainer)}
       
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [Automatically Lazy-loading Google API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#automatically-lazy-loading-google-api)

> the `GoogleApiWrapper` Higher-Order component can be configured by passing a function that will be called with the wrapped component's props and should return the configuration object.

You can pass the `apiKey` prop to the `MapContainer` component.

`maps.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { GoogleApiWrapper, Map } from "google-maps-react";

export class MapContainer extends React.Component<any> {
  render() {
    console.debug("apiKey: ", this.props.apiKey);
    return <Map google={this.props.google} />;
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper((props) => ({
  apiKey: props.apiKey
}))(MapContainer);
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import MapContainer from "./maps";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <MapContainer apiKey="AIzaSyDkXk3MuVjovvaVAnl2wt2j_2ES-INLJ0s" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-75048473-ye9lbb?file=/src/App.tsx)